# Re-activate partner license - causes error

Tags: partner-portal

We de-activated a partner account.

Trying to re-activate the account, we get an error:

> Error: Cannot activate a disabled portal user

[image]

Any one knows how to re-activate it?

*I don't want to create a new account, I think it's wrong behaviour

The User's role is empty as you can see.

[image]

Trying from the Users list gives this error

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Disabled partner user can not be deactivated.
If you want to re-activate users just deactivate them only and not disable them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try going to Setup -> Administer -> Manage Users -> Users -> then find the `UserName` and select `Edit`? You should be able to reset the isActive flag from there by clicking in the checkbox and you can also choose which profile you want to use for the User.

This is different than trying to do it from `Contacts` using the `Manage External User` dialogues.

Comment: Tried that, not working, role is empty as well, getting same error.

Comment: Normally, I'd expect the `role` value to be empty for a `portal user` license as they don't have one. The org I'm working in now dropped their Gold Partner Portal licenses some time ago so can't look to see how those users were configured. A regular portal user quasi-inherits their "role" from the `contact Owner.` They don't ever have a role assigned to them. Sharing in portals isn't via roles. I believe that applies to a Partner Portal User as well. In a community, `sharing groups` would typically be created to handle these these needs. There are LOTS of different ways of managing security.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clairfy, you can "disable" or "deactivate" a portal user. If you disable a portal/community user then you cannot enable them using the technique you show in screenshot (setting Active field true).

If you deactivate a portal/community user (by manually setting Active field on user record to false) then you CAN use the technique you show in screenshot.

From below link, 
"*Permanent loss of the portal user’s association with the contact [if you disable user]
If you later re-enable a contact for portal access, a new portal user is created that is not related to the previous portal user record in any way.*" 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customer_portal_disable_users.htm&language=en&type=0